# How detect feature duplication on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, feature-selection

Here's my data

```
Id   feature1  feature2  feature3 feature4 feature5 feature6
1           4         5         7        7        4        5
2           5         6         8        8        5        5
```

What I want is duplicated data is removed

```
Id   feature1  feature2  feature3 feature6
1           4         5         7        5
2           5         6         8        5
```

Better if duplication is describe as well

```
feature3 is same with feature4
feature2 is same with feature5
```

Usually, I use seaboarn corplot, but I get gen confusing when features grow more than 100

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `T` then `groupby` value , notice `drop_duplicates` and `duplicated` , will not provide the pairs , which means they just give back the duplicated value(not duplicated group)

```
s=df.T.reset_index().groupby([0,1])['index'].apply(tuple)
s[s.str.len()>=2].apply(lambda  x : '{0[0]} is same with {0[1]}'.format(x))
Out[797]: 
0  1
4  5    feature1 is same with feature5
7  8    feature3 is same with feature4
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas-dataframe-t) to transpose your dataframe, use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), and then tranpose your dataframe once more:

```
In [6]: df.T.drop_duplicates().T
Out[6]:
   Id  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature6
0   1         4         5         7         5
1   2         5         6         8         5
```

Comment: can this give explanation like `feature3 is same with feature4`

Comment: You could use [`duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to see which elements *are* duplicates, but it will not tell you which rows they were duplicates of without additional checks.

Comment: @chrisz I am aware of `duplicated` will not distinguish the duplicated pair

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution with **drop_duplicates()** method. However, it looks for rows, so you should apply it to your transposed dataframe and then transpose the result again. Example:

```
data = [
    [4, 5, 7, 7, 4, 5],
    [5, 6, 8, 8, 5, 5],
     ]

columns=['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns)

df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

In order to show which features are duplicated, you can use **duplicated()** method

```
df.T.duplicated().T
```

will show:

```
feature1    False
feature2    False
feature3    False
feature4     True
feature5     True
feature6    False
dtype: bool
```